# Set line width for oracle cmd line

Tags: sql, oracle, relational-database, database-schema

I am using `SET LINESIZE 32767` for displaying properly data in tables, however there is a table that does not accommodate all the columns, also what is the difference between linesize and `SET NUM`

**TABLE**

```
CREATE TABLE STAFF(
EMP_ID NUMBER NOT NULL,
EMP_NAME VARCHAR2(20),
EMP_DOB DATE,
EMP_TEL VARCHAR2(20),
EMP_EMAIL VARCHAR2(50),
EMP_ADDR VARCHAR2(100),
EMP_HIREDATE DATE,
EMP_ENDDATE DATE,
EMP_SALARY NUMBER(7,2),
EMP_SUPERVISOR NUMBER,
 JOB_CODE NUMBER,
 BRA_CODE NUMBER);
```

**INSERT SAMPLE**

```
INSERT INTO STAFF VALUES (NULL,'Andres Baravalle',to_date('25/03/1975','dd/mm/YYYY'),'723 3403-2817','andres.baravalle@live.co.uk','P.O. Box 879, 1742 Porttitor',to_date('15/04/2007','dd/mm/YYYY'),to_date('19/02/2007','dd/mm/YYYY'),49670,NULL,1,10);
```

`SELECT * FROM STAFF;` yields the following

[image: output]

Edit----

Guys how can i get rid of all the space in the timestamp attributes

[image: Get rid of space]

Comment: :) Anyone has any suggestions?

Comment: Don't you need to do some column formatting as well to make it fit? Compress some of the ones that are too wide: "col emp_id format a6" widen those that are wrapping on you.

Comment: Heya Glenn, what does "col emp_id format a6" exactly do?

Comment: @Jose_David_Garcia_Llanos Sets the column emp_id to use only 6 characters of space. A lot of your columns can be narrowed down. Check the sqlplus reference, there are a bunch of other column formatting options.

Comment: Is it the same as setting the data type to varchar2(6) or char(6)?

Comment: How can i get rid of all that space in the columns where TIMESTAMP is being used? btw i am using 'TIMESTAMP(0)

Comment: @Jose_David_Garcia_Llanos See examples here  http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve013.htm#BACHCABF

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**SET LINESIZE** sets the total number of characters that SQL*Plus displays on one line before beginning a new line.

However **SET NUM** is totaly different and sets the default width for displaying numbers.

see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12040.htm)

try setting also your pagesize to be able to see all your table content n one page :

```
set pagesize n
```

and increasing your linesize

Comment: Thanks the link to the user guide helped

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your console is wrapping for you.  Have you tried outputting that data to a text file and opening it in a proper text editor?  Looking it through a console is always going to be constrained by the limits of the console.  Spool it out to a file and see what you get.

Comment: +1 - Another alternative would be to increase the horizontal width of the console.

Comment: Yeah, except that he's got that crazy 32767 width thing going on.  I suppose there is hardware that exists somewhere to get a display up that displays 32767 readable characters horizontally.  Actually... I WANT ONE!

Comment: I got it working by setting both screen buffer size and linesize to 300

Answer (score 1):

Additionally answer you last edit, you can reformat the various columns using "column".

```
COLUMN emp_id format a20
COLUMN emp_tel format a15
COLUMN dept_time format a21
COLUMN arrv_time format a21
```

Which will format the fields above and wrap excess onto the next line.